# Using a double :through :through in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I am trying very hard to figure out the database design for this and I cannot quite get it.

A `User` belongs to many `Networks` and has one `Role` in each `Network`. Multiple `Users` may have the same `Role` in a `Network` (Admin, Editor, Viewer, etc.). The main piece of data is an `Event`. A `User` can create/view/edit/destroy `Events` based on their `Role` in the `Network`.

Does the user get to Events via through through?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :roles
    has_many :networks, :through => :roles
    has_many :events, :through => :networks
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :network
    has_many :users
end

class Networks < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :roles
    has_many :users, :through => :roles
    has_many :events
end

class Events < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :network
    has_many :roles, :through => :network
    has_many :users, :through => :roles
end
```

I don't know if I am way off, or really close to what I am looking for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can multiple users act on a single event? From your description, it seems like they cannot, but the way you're trying to model it, they can.

Comment: Yes they can. Multiple users can edit or view or destroy an event. There may only be 1 user that can do that, but it can be many.
I don't know if its better to have a User_Network table and a Role column. And then a Roles table, but then Networks can't have custom Roles they can reuse.

Comment: I have been looking through everything on CanCan and Devise and cannot figure out something that exactly fits my needs. I want an admin of a network to be able to create reusable roles. If you can point me to any other threads, that would work for me.